# Admin in Terminal, logged on Family's session

Tags: macos, vpn, hosts

I have a weird problem. I'm trying to connect on my VPN with Mac 10.7.5 (Java 7 U45, Citrix Receiver 11.8) but when I do, JSam is not able to write in Hosts file.

So my Mac session is called "Family" but when I go in Terminal and type `whoami`, I get: Admin.

My question is, is it normal and if not, how can I see "Family" in Terminal? Or, how can I give proper rights to Family or Admin so when I connect on my office VPN, Citrix will be able to write in hosts file.

Comment: The guide on [Ask] will help you refine your question by showing what you've tried and/or what exactly "you don't get". Feel free to try editing in as much details as possible and to show what step is failing or doesn't make sense. We love details here.

Comment: How did you setup Admin and Family they are not standard use names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host mapping - "JSAM modifies the hosts file if you choose Automatic host-mapping under Users > User Roles > Role > SAM > Options > Java SAM Options" (from [here](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/sa8.0/topics/reference/general/secure-access-csc-jsam.html)). Which is apparently running on the server side. If you are managing the server, try disabling host mapping unless you need it. At the very least, disable it temporarily and see if everything else works as expected. (If you can do everything you need without host mapping, then leave it turned off.)

Looks like if hosts file modification is enabled, the client needs to run as admin or root (see [here](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/sa8.0/topics/reference/general/secure-access-csc-required-rights.html)) and should be prompting you for the admin password for your account on launch. If your local account does not have administrative permissions, then it would not be able to modify the hosts file. You'd need to log in as an administrator, not a user.

You haven't made it clear whether Terminal output is from your local machine or the remote one.

Comment: @Nixon: I can't change the settings since we have like 20 Citrix servers (Load balanced) over our firm. I can't set the hosts file with all servers/IP on all of our lawyer's laptop.

Without doing SU or SUDO, I can browser with terminal to the hosts file and edit it. The thing is, it looks like to be Citrix that can't edit that file. I'm confused...

Comment: If the end users (I assume the lawyers?) can't run the client without getting the hosts file error, then they must not be running as administrators on their own machines. The host file changes must be done locally by an admin-level account. By default on OS X /etc/hosts is owned by root:wheel, so users cannot change it. If you are logging in as admin, you would be able to change it from your account by authenticating. I can't see a way to allow changes without also giving all users admin privileges.